# Change of name in visa granted?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

My passport has the given name:

- Numaan Muneer
- No surname

I was granted  visit visa to the UK today , it states my name as Muneer Numaan,
is that a problem?

Comment: In what format did you enter your name in your visa application? Personally, I’d consider contacting the issuing centre to check.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fine as the visa is issued with the name in you passport. It is common for the surname/given name in a passport to not be given.

Comment: but the name in visa says Muneer Numaan not Numaan Muneer is that okay?

Comment: @NumaanMuneer That will be fine, it is clear it is the same person

Comment: @Daniil Do you have an official source for your answer? It’s not 100% clear to me for example that airlines would accept ‘Muneer Numaan’ as being the same as ‘Numaan Muneer’

Comment: I believe you should contact UKVI here: https://contactnumbers.buzz/ukvi/ and ask their advice. Whilst to us it is obvious it is the same person, to an Immigration Officer it may not be so obvious. Numaan Muneer and Muneer Numaan can very well be two different people. Did you apply for your visa as "Muneer Numaan?" If you did then the onus is yours. If you didn't then contact them to rectify their mistake.